# return expression result rather than a node or propery value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to return a regex result of a property?

something like

```
MATCH (n) where n.message =~ '.*OA-[0-9]*' 
RETURN APPLY_REGEX(n.message,'MY_REGEX')
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  What do you want the regex result?  What would that object do for you?  In this case, your regex doesn't have any capturing groups or anything, so a hypothetical "apply_regex" would only really give you a true/false match, right?   FWIW, I don't think you can do this anyway with neo4j, but your best bet would be to return the actual node `n`, then look at its `message` property.   But your question needs clarification....

Comment: You probably have to do that in client code.